# Wrong video file header causes video players to fail. Any suggestions for recovering?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, mp4, file-corruption

I have this video: [Google Drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1boU4VymEqRZ34p93MK3MHf9G3kuRP8JJ/view?usp=share_link), and it fails to be played by any video player. I tried fixing it with various tools like VLC, ffmpeg and gpac's mp4box, but none of them worked. More specifically, when i ran `ffmpeg -i 0002201.mp4 -c copy e.mp4` in an attempt to re-encode video, i got the following output:

```
ffmpeg version n6.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.1 (GCC) 20230201
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-amf --enable-avisynth --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-lto --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libjxl --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librav1e --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-shared --enable-version3 --enable-vulkan
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55d06173fdc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 0).
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55d06173fdc0] stream 1, offset 0x13008: partial file
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55d06173fdc0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(bt709), 1920x1080, 33673 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '0002201.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537331968
    compatible_brands: qt  CAEP
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Canon
    com.apple.quicktime.model: Canon PowerShot SX50 HS
    com.apple.quicktime.rating.user: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.copyright:         
    com.apple.quicktime.author:         
    creation_time   : 2015-12-27T09:09:28.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:09.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 60 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(bt709), 1920x1080, 33673 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-12-27T09:09:28.000000Z
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-12-27T09:09:28.000000Z
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
[mp4 @ 0x55d061752a40] Could not find tag for codec pcm_s16le in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container
[out#0/mp4 @ 0x55d061751600] Could not write header (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
[aost#0:1/copy @ 0x55d0617575c0] Error initializing output stream: 
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

As far as i can understand, the error is in the video's header section, which suggests that content is not corrupt and the video still can be recovered. Which tools did you successfully use to fix mp4 files? Maybe someone got a similar error and known a solution? Any suggestions are very welcome, though i would really appreciate if the tools are available natively on (arch) linux. Thanks in advance.

(Also, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xgy4iRGWB3O-1_XffBKBichsFNN5pLfZ/view?usp=share_link)'s another video for reference. In this case, it plays until ~7th second and then freezes.)

Comment: Entire file is 74KB. It's not a video. It has the right header, ftypqt, it even includes 'Canon PowerShot SX50 HS' but there's not enough room for any content. Even Google Drive says - https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWp6g.png

Comment: Just in case i added another example, but it looks like you're right. Thanks anyway.

Comment: 2nd video **is** under 7s long. Slightly broken, but not enough that it's confused about the duration. File size 7.7MB. Tiny. Something went badly wrong before you got to this file.

Comment: I just checked the manual, the SX50 shoots in MOV, so someone's already tried to convert these… & apparently failed ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mdat atom (the actual video data) is 43237748 in size or better said *should* be. File itself is only 74473 bytes. Ergo, file is truncated, you're missing about 43237748 bytes of data. Actual data inside mdat that remains consists of nothing but zeros.

[image]

Funnily enough the moov atom is fine, the offset's it's pointing to correspond with mdat atom size. Since moov is typically created once the recording is stopped it suggests the file was truncated after the video was recorded (for example while being copied).

[image]

> As far as i can understand, the error is in the video's header
> section, which suggests that content is not corrupt and the video
> still can be recovered.

So, no this appears to be incorrect assumption. 'Header' and index look fine, it's actually the video data that is lacking.